# I can't locate my setup executable made by the Inno Setup Compiler

Tags: inno-setup

I was trying to make my programs installer file, but I made a terrible mistake. I forgot to add the `OutputDir` settings to the script but I've already compiled my script and I can't find my setup file.

Here's the script:

```
[Setup]
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup
```

There is no `OutputDir` setting. And I compiled it without noticing it.

I currently have 5 disc drives(?) and I made my script file in the `G` directory which is a 64GB USB flash drive.

I asked ChatGPT and it said if the compiler couldn't find the `OutputDir` settings then it will make the setup file in the same directory where the setup script is located, but I didn't find any .exe files in my USB. Plus, I used the `find` command to find the `.exe` file but it took too long and what it found before I aborted the process were all Windows 10, 11 system or setup files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation for `OutputDir` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_outputdir) says:

> By default, it creates a directory named "Output" under the directory containing the script for this.

---

In Inno Setup Compiler IDE, you can also use *Build > Open Output Folder* to locate the output files.